# Redux data undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, axios

In logger seen anything is normal data loaded successfully.

 You can see it by follow this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTLpr.jpg

 But why this crypto props is undefined and how to fix it. 
Does anyone have any idea?

---

Component

```
   class CryptoContainer extends Component {
           componentWillMount(){
             this.props.Fetchcoin()
           }


    renderCoinCards() {
                 const { crypto } = this.props;
                 console.log('Crypto : '+crypto) 
     return crypto.data.map((coin,index) => //Add this 
        <CoinCard 
            key={coin.name}
            coin_name={coin.name}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            price_usd={coin.price_usd}
            percent_change_24h={coin.percent_change_24h}
            percent_change_7d={coin.percent_change_7d}
        />
    ) 
}  
         }


         function mapStatetoProps(state){
           return{
             crypto:state.crypto  
           }
         }

         export default connect(mapStatetoProps,{Fetchcoin})(CryptoContainer)
>
```

Action

```
export default function FetchCoin(){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type:FETCHING_COIN_DATA})
        return axios.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com//v1/ticker/?limit=10`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({type:FETCHING_COIN_DATA_SUCCESS,payload:res.data})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({type:FETCHING_COIN_DATA_FAIL,payload:err.data})
            })
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
 const initialState = {
        isFetching: null,
        data: [],
        hasError: false,
        errorMessage: null
    }
    export default function (state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case FETCHING_COIN_DATA:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: true,
                    data: null,
                    hasError: false,
                    errorMessage: null
                })
            case FETCHING_COIN_DATA_SUCCESS:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    data: action.payload,
                    hasError: false,
                    errorMessage: null
                })
            case FETCHING_COIN_DATA_FAIL:
                return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isFetching: false,
                    data: action.payload,
                    hasError: true,
                    errorMessage: action.err
                })
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

And store

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk,promise,logger)

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    crypto:CyptoReducer
})

const Store = createStore(
    rootReducer,middleware
)

export default Store
```

I fixed misspelling in store but when I add crypto.data.map() in renderCoinCard
data seem still not working debugger shown

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: Shot in the dark here but there doesn't seem to be a place where you set `crypto` on the state in the reducer.  You set `data` from payload, but in your `mapStateToProps` you pull `crypto` from the state.

Comment: Not sure where you are calling your render function but it might simply be that renderCoins() is called before the data is ready. You might simply want to do a `if (!crypto.data) return false;` guard function before your try an map over data that is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your declaration of rootReducer.Here you have mentioned **"cypto"** instead of **"crypto"**. Fix this and it will work as here only redux declares a reducer and as you have declared here as "cypto" it expects "cypto" and fails.

Comment: Thanks for answer but data value in crypto is still null.

Comment: It is strange everything seems to be fine except "crypto:CyptoReducer" but I think it is a typo from your side so it's ok . Once again cross check from this tutorial https://medium.com/react-native-training/bitcoin-ripple-ethereum-price-checker-with-react-native-redux-e9d076037092 which you might have followed while developing this app to check if you have missed out anything.